# number of input channels does not match corresponding dimension of filter in Keras

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am using keras to build a model based on the Resnet50, the following code is shown below

```python
input_crop = Input(shape=(3, 224, 224))

# extract feature from image crop
resnet = ResNet50(include_top=False, weights='imagenet')
for layer in resnet.layers:  # set resnet as non-trainable
    layer.trainable = False

crop_encoded = resnet(input_crop)
```

However, I got an error

> 'ValueError: number of input channels does not match corresponding
>   dimension of filter, 224 != 3'

how can I fix it?

Comment: What backend are you using and what are the contents of your keras.json file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Such errors are routinely produced due to the different image format used by the Theano & TensorFlow [backends](https://keras.io/backend/) for Keras. In your case, the images are obviously in `channels_first` format (Theano), while most probably you use a TensorFlow backend which needs them in `channels_last` format.

The [MNIST CNN example](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_cnn.py) in Keras provides a nice way to make your code immune to such issues, i.e. working for both Theano & TensorFlow backends - here is an adaptation for your data:

```python
from keras import backend as K

img_rows, img_cols = 224, 224

if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    input_crop = input_crop.reshape(input_crop.shape[0], 3, img_rows, img_cols)
    input_shape = (3, img_rows, img_cols)
else:
    input_crop = input_crop.reshape(input_crop.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 3)
    input_shape = (img_rows, img_cols, 3)

input_crop = Input(shape=input_shape)
```

Comment: What is `input_crop` as per your answer, getting `AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'reshape'` even though I defined it as `input_crop = Input(shape=(3, img_width, img_height))`

Comment: @Laxmikant check the linked MNIST example; `input_crop` (`x_train` or `x_test` there) is returned by the [`mnist.load_data`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/datasets/mnist.py#L18) Keras function - it is a Numpy array and not a tensor