# ValueError: number of input channels does not match corresponding dimension of filter, 512 != 3

Tags: python, keras-layer, channel

It seems [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45909569/number-of-input-channels-does-not-match-corresponding-dimension-of-filter-in-ker), tried its solution but getting

```
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'reshape'
```

I am using keras to build a model based on the VGG16, the following code is shown below

```
if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    input_shape = (3, 256, 256)
else:
    input_shape = (256, 256, 3)
input_image = Input(shape=input_shape)
base_model = VGG16( weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=input_shape)
```

This is base model input output

```
base_model.input
base_model.output
<tf.Tensor 'input_14:0' shape=(?, 256, 256, 3) dtype=float32>
<tf.Tensor 'block5_pool_13/MaxPool:0' shape=(?, 8, 8, 512) dtype=float32>
```

Here we can see, input channels are `3` but it returns output channels as `512`.
(Not sure if it has anything to do with exception thrown.)
As far as I understand, it is not matching the Channels in the input layer for the CNN. I'm not getting hot to fix it?

Here are the CNN layers:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (5, 5), input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
#model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=model(base_model.output))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

The `Model()` method is throwing below error:

```
ValueError: number of input channels does not match corresponding dimension of filter, 512 != 3

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-66-bace1b0f7f30> in <module>()
     23 model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
     24 #model.add(Activation('softmax'))
---> 25 model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=model(base_model.output))
     26 model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
     27               optimizer='rmsprop',

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.py in __call__(self, inputs, **kwargs)
    617 
    618             # Actually call the layer, collecting output(s), mask(s), and shape(s).
--> 619             output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
    620             output_mask = self.compute_mask(inputs, previous_mask)
    621 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/models.py in call(self, inputs, mask)
    577         if not self.built:
    578             self.build()
--> 579         return self.model.call(inputs, mask)
    580 
    581     def build(self, input_shape=None):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.py in call(self, inputs, mask)
   2083             return self._output_tensor_cache[cache_key]
   2084         else:
-> 2085             output_tensors, _, _ = self.run_internal_graph(inputs, masks)
   2086             return output_tensors
   2087 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.py in run_internal_graph(self, inputs, masks)
   2233                                 if 'mask' not in kwargs:
   2234                                     kwargs['mask'] = computed_mask
-> 2235                             output_tensors = _to_list(layer.call(computed_tensor, **kwargs))
   2236                             output_masks = layer.compute_mask(computed_tensor,
   2237                                                               computed_mask)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/layers/convolutional.py in call(self, inputs)
    166                 padding=self.padding,
    167                 data_format=self.data_format,
--> 168                 dilation_rate=self.dilation_rate)
    169         if self.rank == 3:
    170             outputs = K.conv3d(

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py in conv2d(x, kernel, strides, padding, data_format, dilation_rate)
   3339         strides=strides,
   3340         padding=padding,
-> 3341         data_format=tf_data_format)
   3342 
   3343     if data_format == 'channels_first' and tf_data_format == 'NHWC':

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py in convolution(input, filter, padding, strides, dilation_rate, name, data_format)
    779         dilation_rate=dilation_rate,
    780         name=name,
--> 781         data_format=data_format)
    782     return op(input, filter)
    783 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py in __init__(self, input_shape, filter_shape, padding, strides, dilation_rate, name, data_format)
    839           "number of input channels does not match corresponding dimension of "
    840           "filter, {} != {}".format(input_channels_dim,
--> 841                                     filter_shape[num_spatial_dims]))
    842 
    843     strides, dilation_rate = _get_strides_and_dilation_rate(

ValueError: number of input channels does not match corresponding dimension of filter, 512 != 3
```

Comment: You could try to just modify the input to the layers that you wrote

Comment: i.e. add `model.add(Reshape(target_shape=(128, 128, 2), input_shape=list(base_model.output.get_shape().as_list()[1:])))` as the first layer to your model.

Comment: @Primusa - Thanks, Seems error has gone. I understand as it reshapes the dimension. But not getting what this line does? More specifically what is target_shape here?

Comment: Target shape is what the shape is transformed into. It takes an input_shape and transforms it into target_shape

Comment: @Primusa -Thanks again! Yea, that's obvious we're transforming the shape. (Sorry my question wasnt clear enough earlier).  I wanted to ask you - Why we're considering (128, 128, 2) specifically, I tried to change it to (256, 256, 3) as it is my input_shape, it thrown an error. I'm not able to understand why it is (128, 128, 2). What are these numbers and why we're transforming in to that particular shape. ( I'm newbie to ML and I apologize if this is a silly question)

Comment: The size of the shape its transformed to and the input shape have to be the same. 8*8*512 == 128*128*2, so you can transform the output from VGG16 to 128, 128, 2. The actual numbers are more or less arbitrary as long as the product is the same.

Comment: @Primusa - Thank you very much, I got it now. Please update as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Added as an answer :) Thank you for helping me in my quest for internet points :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can't do anything about the output of VGG16 I figured you could just modify the input layer:

Add this as the first layer for your model:

```
model.add(Reshape(target_shape=(128, 128, 2), input_shape=list(base_model.output.get_shape().as_list()[1:])))
```

What the reshape layer does is that it takes in an `input_shape` and then changes the shape to `target_shape`. This operation is allowed as long as the size of both the input and the target are constant (product of all the numbers are the same).